# Redirected output from console application is VERY inconsistent

Tags: c#, winforms, console-application, redirectstandardoutput

I've got a console application (`steamcmd.exe`) which I want to redirect its output to a textbox in my Winforms application.

https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/client/installer/steamcmd.zip

I've managed to do that, but the output I get is very inconsistent. For example, I start `steamcmd.exe` normally with these arguments

```
+login anonymous +force_install_dir ./unturned/ +app_update 1110390 validate
```

This will install the Unturned game server. The output is perfectly fine. It shows the downloading progress consistently.

But when I start `steamcmd.exe` using my Winforms application and I redirect its output, it becomes super inconsistent, it could stay stuck at 2% and after a few minutes jump to 58%, the get stuck again and jump to 88% etc.

Here is my code:

```
   steamCMDProc = new Process();
   void startSteamCMD()
    {
        steamCMDProc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        steamCMDProc.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(steamCMD_OutputDataReceived);
        steamCMDProc.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(steamCMD_ErrorDataReceived);
        steamCMDProc.Exited += new System.EventHandler(steamCMDProcExited);

        steamCMDProc.StartInfo.FileName = srvInstDir + @"\steamcmd.exe";
        steamCMDProc.StartInfo.Arguments = "login anonymous +force_install_dir ./unturned/ +app_update 1110390 validate";
        steamCMDProc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        steamCMDProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        steamCMDProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        steamCMDProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        steamCMDProc.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
        steamCMDProc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        steamCMDProc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
       
        steamCMDProc.Start(); 
       
        // inputWriter = steamCMDProc.StandardInput; not currently used
        StartThread(steamCMDProcExited); //i start a thread which constantly loops and waits till steamCMD has exited
        steamCMDProc.BeginErrorReadLine();
        steamCMDProc.BeginOutputReadLine();
   }
   void steamCMD_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
   {
         InvokeIfRequired(textBox2, () => //function that checks if invoke is required
         { textBox2.AppendText(e.Data + Environment.NewLine); });
    }

    void steamCMD_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {      
         InvokeIfRequired(textBox2, () =>
         { textBox2.AppendText(e.Data + Environment.NewLine); });
    }
```

Comment: This is normal, programs commonly start buffering their output when it is redirected.  Their programmers deals with it by intentionally flushing output where necessary.  But of course they didn't do that, nothing you can do about that.

Comment: @HansPassant crap